# Show that $\cos t,\,\cos^2 t,\, . . . $ is a linearly independent system in $F$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm faced with this problem which I can't really know how to begin solving it, any help would be appreciated.

> Let $F$ be the real vector space of the functions $f : \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.
>   Show that: $$\cos t,\; \cos^2 t,\; . . . ,\; \cos^n t,\; . . .$$
>   is a linearly independent system in $F$.

Any guidance is welcome.

Comment: What is the inner product on the space $F$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant You don't need an inner product to define (or verify) linear independence (though it may be, admittedly, helpful)

Comment: @GregoryGrant It's not given in the problem.

Comment: **Hint:** It is equivalent to show that the functions $x,x^2,\dots,x^n,\dots$ over $[-1,1]$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that an infinite set is linearly independent it is sufficient to prove that every finite subset of it is linearly independent.

So show that $\{\cos t,\cos^2t,\cos^3 t,....\cos ^n t \}$ linearly independent.

For this note that :$c_1\cos t +...+c_n\cos ^n t=0$ .Putting $t=0$ we have  $c_1+c_2+....+c_n=0$.

Now differentiating w.r.t we get $c_1\sin t+c_2 \sin 2t+...+c_n n\cos^{n-1}t \sin t=0$.Putting $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we get $c_1=0$.

In this way go on differentiating and substitute suitable values (try for $n=3$ first) , you will get $c_i=0\forall i$

Comment: This is really a good answer, but i still can't see how i can generalize that ∀i ci=0
Because so far i have only showed that c1 = 0

Comment: I asked you do for $n=3$ first;Did you do that ? If so have you substituted different values for $t=0,\frac{\pi}{2},\pi$ etc

Comment: I would finish the proof in alternate way: Since $c_1=0$, we get $c_2\cos^2t+...+c_n\cos^nt=0$, so dividing by $\cos t$ we get $c_2\cos t+...+c_n\cos^{n-1}t=0$. Now if we were to assume $n$ is minimal such that the set $\{\cos t,...,\cos^n t\}$ is linearly dependent, we are lead to a contradiction.

Comment: I did and i have finally got it, thank you.
@Wojowu Your help cleared things for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you start with the equation
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \lambda_k \cos^k t = 0.$$
Now consider what this equation means: the equality must be true for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$...

Answer (score 0):

Start from required $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k \cos^k t = 0 \;\;\;\; (1)$$
and now divide through $\cos(t)$. (If first few $a_{i}, i < m$ are $0$ reduce to the case when first coefficient is different from $0$ simply by dividing by $\cos^{m-1}(t)$.)  You have got:

$$a_{1}+\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \cos^k t = 0$$ or
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \cos^k t = -a_{1} \neq 0 \;\;\;\; (2)$$

We can bound $t$ to be from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. It is irrelevant if we include or exclude one of or both values. Now

$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0^{+}} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \cos^k t = -a_{1} \;\;\;\;$$ which means that

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k+1}$$ is bounded since  $\lim\limits_{t \to 0^{+}} \cos^k t = 1$. This means that since $\lim\limits_{t \to \frac{\pi}{2}^{-}} \cos^k t = 0 $ it must be

$$\lim\limits_{t \to \frac{\pi}{2}^{-}} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k+1} \cos^k t = 0$$  contrary to our assumption that it is $-a_{1} \neq 0$.

This means that for all $i$ $a_{i}=0$ so the set of functions is independent.

Comment: Thanks mate, had trouble understanding your solution but now it's crystal clear.